# How to make .ipa file in Xcode 4.3? can't find save to enterprise

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4.3

We built a iphone app and now we would like to export it to an .ipa file so we could drop it in itunes. we we can't figure out how to do this, a lot of tutorials on the internet are related on older versions of xcode.

Could someone help us?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go through menu: Product -> Archive
Then it opens "Arhives" tab in Organizer. Select most recent archive and tap "Distribute" button.
Then select save for enterprise distribution / ad-hoc distribution and save it at your desired location on mac.

Note : You need to have valid certificates/keys in your keychain and its associated provisioning profile for creating an archieve.

Comment: We get the error: "there are no valid certificate/private key pairs in the default keychain.

Comment: If so, I have some questions: 1) Do you have provisioning profile? 2) If answer for first question is NO, do you enrolled in apple developer program?

Comment: Are you able to simply Run or Build your App?

Comment: We can build and run our app succesfully

Comment: Yes, you can't run your program on device, or build for device until you've got one

Comment: On iOS Simulator? Or on real device (iPhone or iPad)?

Comment: IOS Simulator, but we don't have a provisioning profile, do we have to make one?

Comment: You can only make .ipa files out of device-compiled apps.

Comment: Yes you need to ...for that join ios developer program from http://www.developer.apple.com and then you can create it.

Comment: We need to pay 99 dollar a year to develop things. we will probably do this but we don't code that much for nou. thanks anyway.